# Python Google App Engine - Reference uploaded .pkl file on VM

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unix, flask, data-science

I have a python FLASK API deployed on Google App Engine (flex environment rather than standard). In my code I need to reference a file I've downloaded onto the machine.

```
path_to_file_i_want = '~/home/andrew/saved_model.pkl'
with open(clf_path, 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)
```

However I'm getting "No such file or directory". So my question is...

Can I reference a file outside of my code/project directory? If so what am I doing wrong?

Note 1: The file is copied onto the machine due to it's large size (1.5gb)

Note 2: Loading this file in from google cloud storage is too slow

Comment: How have you downloaded the file to the machine?

Answer (score 1):

Things like the `~` are evaluated by the shell (e. g. `bash`).  You are not using one here, so you cannot use the `~` abbreviation.

`~` stands for your home directory.  This is available in Python via the `HOME` environment variable.  This you can combine with the path below using `os.path.join()`:

```
import os

path_to_file_i_want = os.path.join(os.getenv('HOME'),
                                   '/home/andrew/saved_model.pkl')
```